# Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling

Tags: xampp

Whenever I visit http://localhost:8080/wordpress/subcontractor/ it opens, but when I want to go to another page through the navigation bar items the error below shows:

[image]

Please help me fix this issue.

Comment: What does this have to do with Microsoft SQL Server (the `sql-server` tag)? XAMPP servers are based on MySQL/MariaDB.

Answer (score 0):

It shows that URL not found. Did you check the path of the hyperlink to navigate and see if the spellings are match with the actual path you are trying to get to?